# I am having a logic error in this loop (Python 3)

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I have some flight data with a time stamp and it's respective G Load in 2 arrays called Time and gnormal arrays.

The code is supposed to check if a specific index of gnormal is more than 1.05g (Absolute value) and keep going until the value in the array is less than 1.05g (Absolute value). So, for example, if the 2nd index is more than 1.05g and the values are over 1.05g until the 10th index.

The next part is that the difference in time between the 2 ends of the exceeded values is then checked with the time array.

If the time difference is less than 2 seconds, then the maximum in that g load data array is appended to gusts, if it is more than 2 seconds, it is appended to maneuver.

I know that the data does have maneuver loads, I checked manually, but it is only giving me gust results.

Would really appreciate help. Thank you in advance. Am glad to clarify if my explanation isn't adequate, apologies in advance.

Below is the code snippet.

```
gusts = list()
maneuvers = list()
del time[0]
del gnormal[0]
i = 0
while i in range(len(gnormal)):
    if abs(gnormal[i]) >= 1.05:
        start_of_set = i
        i += 1
        while abs(gnormal[i]) <= 1.05 and not i+1 in range(len(gnormal)):
            i += 1
        end_of_set = i
        if time[end_of_set] - time[start_of_set] >= 2:
            maneuvers.insert(1,max(gnormal[start_of_set:end_of_set], key=abs))
        elif time[end_of_set] - time[start_of_set] < 2:
            gusts.insert(1,max(gnormal[start_of_set:end_of_set], key=abs))
        else:
            continue
    i += 1
```

I tried to print out where the if statements go, and I only got gusts, I am not able to figure out exactly what is wrong with it.

2 Examples of input and Expected Output

**#1** Time difference of exceeded values is less than 2 seconds

Input:

Time:
736.93024
737.00458
737.07532
737.14868
737.22125
737.29437
737.36328
737.43359
737.50256
737.57813
737.6524
737.72351

gnormal:
1.02318
1.02788
1.0079
0.98292
0.98223
0.96477
1.05904
1.04175
0.99769
1.00834
0.98445
0.99357

Output:

gusts: 1.05904

**#2** Time difference of exceeded values is more than 2 seconds

Time:
765.13293
765.19598
765.26068
765.32446
765.38989
765.45465
765.51788
765.58655
765.65631
765.72253
765.78723
765.8515
765.91949
765.9826
766.04657
766.11084
766.17529
766.23822
766.3028
766.36829
766.43481
766.50165
766.5647
766.62823
766.69672
766.75989
766.82977
766.89606
766.96228
767.02997
767.0993
767.16461
767.22845
767.29248
767.35883
767.42279
767.4881

gnormal :
0.94777
0.9369
0.92748
0.9208
0.91501
0.90933
0.90344
0.89632
0.88828
0.87894
0.86969
0.86047
0.85246
0.84635
0.84213
0.83792
0.83394
0.82783
0.81861
0.80621
0.80428
0.80239
0.7993
0.79512
0.78993
0.78443
0.77866
0.76944
0.76744
0.77437
0.78987
0.81198
0.83701
0.86403
0.89195
0.91534
0.93668

Output

maneuver : 0.76744

Comment: Please provide sample input & expected output.

Comment: It's generally easier if you don't use multiple lists. Use a list of tuples or dictionaries to keep all the related data together.

Comment: I have added sample input and expected output

Comment: *"I know that the data does have maneuver loads, I checked manually"*: Please explain the desired output for the second example. I don't understand why there should be a maneuver as all values in the second series are less than 1. Moreover the expected output shows 0.76744 as value... How can that be, when it should be the maximum value among values that are greater than 1.05 !?

Comment: If I correct the values in your input to have gnormal > 1.05 paired with diff in time > 2sec, I get the expected output with your code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm crazy, but why do you have the `not` here?

```python
        while abs(gnormal[i]) <= 1.05 and not i+1 in range(len(gnormal)):
            i += 1
```

Seems that would kick you out of the loop immediately, leaving `end_of_set` always set to `start_of_set + 1`.